# Graphing the motion of a driven damped pendulum

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, software, chaos-theory

$ \ddot{\phi}+2 \beta \dot{\phi}+\omega_{0}^{2} \sin \phi=\gamma \omega_{0}^{2} \cos \omega t$

The equation of movement is written above. I´m trying to plot the value of $\phi$ for different values of $\gamma$ by solving the equation numerically in Matlab, but it just seems to be errors in my code. For example I should get this for $\gamma=1.06$:
[image]
but with my code the graph is not even periodic.
Here's my code:

```
clear all
gamma=1.06;
g=9.81;L=0.5;m=1;dair=1.225;muair=1.81e-5;R=0.1;                            
w02=g/L;b=6*pi*dair*muair*R; beta2=b/m;                                                
w=2/3*sqrt(w02);                                                            
syms y(t)
[V] = odeToVectorField(diff(y, 2) == gamma*w02*cos(w*t)-beta2*diff(y)-w02*sin(y)); 
M = matlabFunction(V,'vars', {'t','Y'});
[time,A] = ode45(M,[0 200],[-pi/2 0]);
figure
plot(time,A(:,1))
figure
plot(time,A(:,2))
```

What is wrong?

I don't think the problem is that the transient didn't die out. Here are some graphs for much greater time spans:
[image: t=1000]
[image: t=2000]

Update: I tried out some more values of $\gamma$ and it all seemed to be chaotic. So I drew some bifurcation diagrams.The initial conditions are $[-\frac{\pi}{2},0]$.
The first one is for a time span of 1000:
[image]
And this is for a time span of 4000:
[image]

Why does it seem to be chaotic from the beginning?

Comment: I don't know if Matlab questions are on-topic here, but I'll wait for others who have been longer on this StackExchange site.

Comment: I think [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might then be a better home for this question.

Comment: Did you extend the graph for a long enough time? Force damped oscillations have a transient time and a periodic time.

Comment: [22a: Driven Damped Pendulum: Period Doubling, Chaos, Strange Attractors](http://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/7010/CM_22a_Period_Doubling_Chaos.html).

Comment: Do your parameters $\omega_0$, $\omega$ and $\beta$ match the source of that first image? Does `[-pi/2, 0]` for your initial conditions also match that source? And are those ICs in the right order (i.e., is that `[phi-dot, phi]` order or `[phi, phi-dot]` order)?

Comment: It might also be helpful to include *what* you are trying to model, rather than just the equation.

Comment: No it does not. The first image is just an indication of what I should get, which I did by increasing the drag. The initial conditions are not the same either, but by matching them to [0 0] does not help. And yes, the order of the initial conditions are $[\phi  \: \dot{\phi} ]$

Comment: Okay, then I wouldn't expect a match (or even a partial replication) until the parameters match. Testing in Python, I get 2 very different answers depending on the ODE solver method (RK45 vs LSODA; cf. [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html))

Comment: Of course the exact solutions shouldn't match, but shouldn't the behavior be similar? The bifurcation diagrams are added if it's helpful.

Comment: No, the behavior may not be the same for chaotic systems.

Comment: But the system is only chaotic if $\gamma>1.0829$ right?

Comment: My understanding from reading Frobenius' link above is that $\gamma>1.0829$ is the condition for the Taylor parameters $\omega_0=1.5$, $\omega=1$, $2\beta=0.75$. If you are changing those parameters, then the chaotic limit a.s. is going to change.

Comment: Yes, I think this is another route to chaos as I don't see period-doubling (which is the route for the Taylor parameters).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is much simpler than I thought: I need to add more drag. The drag in the original code is the Stokes's law for spheres moving in air, and the drag is very small, $\beta=0.0065$ to be specific. In a linear driven damped oscillator the solution has a $e^{-\beta t}$ in it, but in this case it's not exactly the same (I don't know the exact solution so any comment on this is appreciated). In fact, in my simulation the system seemed to be chaotic, with this graph of a time span of $10^{6}$ :
[image]
but if I define $2\beta=20$ directly, I get this with a time span of only $20$:
[image]

Comment: Very interesting find, when weak damping interacts with the forcing function to cause a chaotic response.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `t=200` isn't sufficient time to work through the transients.

The solution has an `exp(-β t)` term in it for the transient and based on the values supplied, `β ≈ 0.0065`. I assume `beta2 = β^2`.

So for `exp(-β t)=0.1` you need `t>356`. You only simulate to `t=200`.

It pays to make a math model (using small-angle approximations) before jumping into simulation so you understand what the computer spits out.

Comment: I actually tried for values of t of much greater values (t=400, 1000, 10000), and it never reached the periodic motion. I didn't expect the transient to be so long.

Comment: The graphs for t=1000 and t=2000 are added in the original post.

Comment: beta2 is clearly *not* $\beta^2$

Comment: @KyleKanos - yes I see that now. But nevertheless, the point stands that sufficient simulation time is needed to overcome the transient behavior.

Comment: OP has posted graphs well beyond t=356 which do not show an end to the transient behavior. I imagine there is something else at play here.